# How to clear every trace of Kaspersky after messed up uninstallation

Tags: windows, uninstall, kaspersky

About a year ago, I made a big mistake: instead of waiting for my "not responding" Control Panel window, I just went to Program Files and deleted the whole Kaspersky Folder. Back then I thought that's it, it was uninstalled.

Now, I want to install Bitdefender. But when I run the installer, it says that Kaspersky is installed and that Bitdefender can't be installed along with it. I tried removing the registry entries for Kaspersky but it still doesn't work.
How can I fix this?

PS. Kaspersky Antivirus is still listed in Control Panel > Programs & Features.

Comment: Reinstall kaspersky then uninstall it properly using programs and features, this time be patient.

Comment: @Moab Do I need to install the same version?

Comment: Try this removal tool first>>https://support.kaspersky.com/common/uninstall/1464